# How to use a .env file to setup/configure a Webpack config

Tags: webpack, configuration, environment-variables

I'm having issues using `.env` variables to configure my Webpack config.
Let me explain: I want to be able to use a `.env` file to configure/setup my Webpack config. In my case, this is setting up a *proxy URL* for BrowserSync. The idea is to make it simple/easy to change certain (predefined) parts of the wp-config, rather than diving into the wp-config itself.

Example of the `.env` file:

```
APP_NAME=Test Application
PROXY_URL=test-application.test
```

Webpack config example:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 7777,
            proxy: PROXY_URL // inserted from .env
        })
    ],
});
```

I have been fiddling around with `webpack.DefinePlugin` and the `Dotenv` npm module, but these seem to be unreachable (undefined) inside the actual Webpack config (but works fine inside the application itself, index.js etc.).

So my questions is; is this doable? and what would be the easiest/cleanest way to achieve this?

Comment: which library are you using to handle .env files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package.

First parse the .env file:

`var dotenv = require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'});
 const devURL = dotenv.parsed.BASE_URL;
 const devPORT = dotenv.parsed.PORT;`

Then you can use it in your config.

`devServer: {
     host: devURL || '0.0.0.0',
     port: devPORT || 9000,
 }`